# Has anyone seen a Micro-USB socket which installs with the socket perpendicular to the PCB?

Tags: pcb, usb

Has anyone seen a Micro-USB socket which installs with the socket perpendicular to the PCB?

You'd think that this would be readily available as a standard option but it seems to be hard to come by. We have a situation where use of such a connector would be significantly beneficial.

Answer (score 3):

Micro USB (as also any other USB) is available in *vertical board mounted* form. Those words in italics should provide you some suitable search results.

For instance, [this one](http://www.gct.co/connector/?series=USB3105) from Global Connector Technology, part number USB3105:

[image: microUSB vertical]

The GCT [USB connector page](http://www.gct.co/usb-connectors/vertical.aspx?Style=Micro&) for Micro USB has a few other vertical board mounted ones as well.

Comment: Also, Molex parts no. 105133-0011 and -0001.